# Instantiate a Object below another object instead of above

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, i created a GIF to show what is currently happen.

[GIF with my current problem](https://giphy.com/gifs/rR7pjnrdQ6OyFE4ptJ/fullscreen)

and

Awhat I want

[image]

I have a List of GameObject which add the bodyParts temp and Instantiate it in the correct time and position.
Now this is working like expected, but i want this new bodyParts below another object instead of above.
As you can see the Head is "under" the new body parts, but it should always on Top and every new part should spawn under the next. (only should looks like! I dont want to change the Z position.)

**i tried** :

```
bodyParts.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
```

to change the Hierarchy, but this do nothing. I also can drag and drop the Clones to a other position in Hierarchy but they just stay at the same position (above another).

Is this possible and what should i have to do?

**Here some of my Code which makes the process:**

```
    private void CreateBodyParts()
    {
        if (snakeBody.Count == 0)
        {
            
            GameObject temp1 = Instantiate(bodyParts[0], transform.position, transform.rotation, transform);
            if (!temp1.GetComponent<MarkerManager>())
                temp1.AddComponent<MarkerManager>();
            if (!temp1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>())
            {
                temp1.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                temp1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0;
            }
            snakeBody.Add(temp1);        
            bodyParts.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        MarkerManager markM = snakeBody[snakeBody.Count - 1].GetComponent<MarkerManager>();
        if (countUp == 0)
        {
            markM.ClearMarkerList();
        }
        countUp += Time.deltaTime;
        if (countUp >= distanceBetween)
        {
            GameObject temp = Instantiate(bodyParts[0], markM.markerList[0].position, markM.markerList[0].rotation, transform);
  
            if (!temp.GetComponent<MarkerManager>())
                temp.AddComponent<MarkerManager>();
            if (!temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>())
            {
                temp.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0;
            }
            snakeBody.Add(temp);
            
            bodyParts.RemoveAt(0);
            temp.GetComponent<MarkerManager>().ClearMarkerList();
            countUp = 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are these objects children of a Canvas?  Reordering objects parented under a canvas will change their render order.  Maybe you had the editor paused while changing the order of the parts, game must be running to see the change.

Comment: I had to define a Layer for my objects and set a LayerOrder. The LayerOrder automatically sorts from large to small. so now it works as expected. But thanks for trying to help me. I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i found the working Solution.**

*It has nothing to do with which hierarchy order GameObjects spawn in.*

*Just the Layer and the LayerOrder are responsible for it.*

So I give my parent object a specific layer name (manually in the inspector under "Additional Settings" or programmatically)

I chose the programmatic way...

Any newly spawned GameObject that is Child would get a lower number

```
yourGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingLayerID = SortingLayer.NameToID("Player");
yourGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingOrder = -snakeBody.Count;
```